# Determine if function call is static

Tags: c#, function, static

I have a function `SerializeUser` in the Class `User`. 
This function does not have a Parameter.

I want to have different functionality in these two types of function calls:

```
User.SerializeUser(); //Do sth...
```

and

```
User u = new User();
u.SerializeUser(); //Do sth else...
```

Is it possible to check if it is a static function call or a non static function call?

Comment: You could name them differently...?! But no, you can't write the code you've given in your example. Kindly explain *why* you would want such an abomination!

Comment: You can't have a non-static `SerializeUser` and a static `SerializeUser` on the same class.  But why would you want to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "check"?  Your first sample calls a `static` method, your second sample calls an instance method.  (Note: I doubt the compiler will allow you to have otherwise identical methods, but I could be mistaken.)  It's not really clear what you're actually trying to accomplish here.

Comment: Seems confusing, surely they would do quite different things and so deserve more descriptive names.

Answer (score 4):

No, a function cannot be both static and non-static.

What you *can* do is create two methods, one static, and one non-static, although they will need to have different signatures.  If you want them both to accept no arguments, they will have to have a different name, which is likely for the best anyway; given that one is acting on an instance and another isn't, there is almost certainly something at least somewhat different about what the methods are doing that you should reflect in their name.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're confusing here is that if you define one method, `SerializeUser()` on your `User` object, you will not be able to call `User.SerializeUser()` unless it is static. If it *is* static, then you won't be able to do `new User().SerializeUser()` - you can only do both with two methods, same name or not, and you can only have the same name if you differentiate their signatures so the compiler can resolve which one to use.

The only way this makes sense as something you'd *want* to do is if the instance method passes the instance as an argument to the static method, and the static method accepts an instance as a parameter, i.e.:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public static void Method(MyClass c = null)
        {
            if (c == null)
            {
                //Do Stuff From Static
            }
            else
            {
                //Do Different Stuff With Instance
            }
        }  

        public void Method()
        {
            Method(this);
        }
    }
}
```

You can also use something else to differentiate them, such as a boolean with a default value, or without a default value. Ex. if the static method has a `bool flag = false` parameter, then the instance method could call it with `flag = true` and then you can make the behavior differentiate. This is slightly nasty code, though, as it hides the method behind tricky overload resolution.

To answer your question directly you can check whether the current method is static with `MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().IsStatic`, but I don't think that will actually be of use to you in this situation.

Looking at your code, though, I imagine what you want is this:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class User
    {
        public static string SerializeUser(User u = null)
        {
            if (u != null)
                return u.SerializeUser();
            else
                return "something"; //default(User).SerializeUser();?
        }
    }

    public static class UserExtensions
    {
        public static string SerializeUser(this User u)
        {
            //return however you serialize your user.
        }
    }
}
```